# Go through vs get through vs get over

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Go through /get through/ Go over
To me, they all seem like 'to overcome something '..
Are they interchangeable? 
I read through the post about get through vs go through on this site but I still don't get it..

Answer (score 2):

To go through an ordeal... to experience it

To get through an ordeal...to survive it

To get over an ordeal ... to put it in the past and move on to other things

Comment: But "go over" is different.